# Programatically Invoking LUIS Outside the Message Controler

Tags: frameworks, botframework, bots, azure-language-understanding

I'm writting a bot application that uses a Prompt Dialog to interact with users.
The idea here is when a user selects a certain option a message should be sent to LUIS that will be processing the request via ML.
Thought about two ways to get it done.
1 - Invoke LUIS directly
2 - Simulate a user entry to make sure the message would pass by the Message Controller and finally the Root Dialog which will be making a LUIS call
Makes sense?
I've tried something like this but it didn't work.

```
public virtual async Task ChoiceReceivedAsync_MainMenuOption(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<MainMenuOption> activity)
    {
              ...
                        IMessageActivity message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
                        message.Text = "Como e a seguranca da escola?";
                        message.TextFormat = "plain";
                        message.Locale = "en-Us";              
                        var luisAttributes = new LuisModelAttribute(BellaMain.GlobalVariable.LuisModelID, BellaMain.GlobalVariable.LuisSubscriptionKey);
                        var luisService = new LuisService(luisAttributes);
                        await Conversation.SendAsync(message, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog(luisService));
    }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: `uses a Prompt Dialog to interact with users` Are you using *PromptDialog.Choice* method in your RootDialog? Could you show the code snippet of your Prompt Dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to call LUIS by mocking up a new Activity to send to the bot is not recommended.
Instead you should call LUIS through a simple request using an HttpClient.

[Here is a sample from the LUIS Endpoint API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5819c76f40a6350ce09de1ac/operations/5819c77140a63516d81aee78):

Copy-pasted example:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;

namespace CSHttpClientSample
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            MakeRequest();
            Console.WriteLine("Hit ENTER to exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static async void MakeRequest()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

            // Request headers
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "{subscription key}");

            // Request parameters
            queryString["timezoneOffset"] = "{number}";
            queryString["verbose"] = "{boolean}";
            queryString["spellCheck"] = "{boolean}";
            queryString["staging"] = "{boolean}";
            queryString["bing-spell-check-subscription-key"] = "{string}";
            queryString["log"] = "{boolean}";
            var uri = "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/{appId}?q={q}&" + queryString;

            var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
        }
    }
}
```